# How can I match everything except for the expression with a regex?

Tags: regex, pandas

I have the following text:

```
MSH 1A C3
MSH B4-14 c3-1
AU1 C4 2
MA2A C1 1
```

And I want to take this information from it:

```
MSH 1A
MSH B4-14
AU1
MA2A
```

I tried this regex to highlight the C's:

```
(( C[0-9].*)|( c[0-9].*))
```

How can I match everything except for what I highlighted in my regex? This needs to be a one-line regex.

Comment: You can replace the matches with an empty string using `\s[Cc]\d.*` https://regex101.com/r/n276gM/1 or match them instead `^.*?(?=\s*[Cc]\d)` https://regex101.com/r/IwMEEH/1

Comment: Hi, my code always works if the pattern is accepted on regexr.com. In this case, even though it worked on regex101.com, it didn't in regexr.com nor on my code. Unfortunately, in this case, I can't replace the matches with an empty string, my code works on extracting the matching pattern to do other stuff.

Comment: Can you please add the code to the question?

Comment: ID = df_elements['POINT_ID'].str.extract('^.*?(?=\s*[Cc]\d)', expand=False)

Comment: it creates the ID dataframe to extract the names that I want, based on the regex, I will use this later to do a merge

Comment: It could be like this `df_elements['POINT_ID'] = df_elements['POINT_ID'].str.replace(r'\s[Cc]\d.*', "")` or like this `df_elements['POINT_ID'] = df_elements['POINT_ID'].str.extract('^(.*?)(?=\s*[Cc]\d)', expand=False)`

Comment: You may try with pattern (([A-BD-Z0-9\- ]+)\s*[Cc]([\d\-]?))+ Matches will be on group #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten the pattern using a charaxcter class `[Cc]`.

Using replace with an empty string:

```
df_elements['POINT_ID'] = df_elements['POINT_ID'].str.replace(r'\s[Cc]\d.*', "")
```

Using extract with a capture group:

```
df_elements['POINT_ID'] = df_elements['POINT_ID'].str.extract('^(.*?)(?=\s*[Cc]\d)', expand=False)
```

Both will result in:

```
    POINT_ID
0     MSH 1A
1  MSH B4-14
2        AU1
3       MA2A
```